# fetch data from access database in a list view in C#

Tags: c#, listview

**I want to fetch data from access database in a list view in C#...**

This is what I'm using :

```
 private void LstVwBrandNmO_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "select BrandName from Inventory";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, bookConn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

What to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after fetching the data in datatable just assign the datasource property of Listiew like this
ListView.DataSource = dt

and use databind function to bind the datasource to the list

ListView.DataBind();

before this make sure you have define Itemtemplate with <%#EVAL#> to bind the values in the datasource

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a loop to add data to list like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already defined the columns and view in your ListView, you may simply set the ListView's `ItemsSource` to DataTable:

```
listView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

If you wanna do it programmatically, then this may help:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows) {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dataRow[0].ToString());

    for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
        item.SubItems.Add(dataRow[i].ToString());
    }
    listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```